# How can i add a progressbar under each pictureBox and how can i show each download file progress in the progressbar?

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form1 im creating 8 pictureBoxes 4 on left panel and 4 on a right panel.

```
pbs = new PictureBox[8];
            for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
            {
                pbs[i] = new PictureBox();
                pbs[i].MouseEnter += globalPbsMouseEnterEvent;
                pbs[i].MouseLeave += globalPbsMouseLeaveEvent;
                pbs[i].Tag = "PB" + i.ToString();
                pbs[i].Size = new Size(100, 100);
                pbs[i].Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 60);
                pbs[i].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                pbs[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                Panel p = i < 4 ? panel1 : panel2;
                p.Controls.Add(pbs[i]);
                pbs[i].BringToFront();
            }
```

How can i add a thin progressBar under each pictureBox ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but with this kind of asking no one is going to answer. You have to put your focus on the most important detail that you are in trouble with, otherwise I can say most of people don't have the time to review your code.

Comment: I agree with @MahanGM. While reading your code and understanding what is the problem I'd answer 3-4 questions. So be specific and post only relevant part of the code to get help

Comment: Ok sorry. So the question is how do i add a thin progressBar under each pictureBox ?

Comment: You know how to add a PictureBox so why wouldn't you know how to add a ProgressBar as well?  You're usually ahead by creating a UserControl, helps you to focus on one thing at a time and makes the designer useful.

Comment: Right i did it just now.

Answer (score 0):

Just did it now.
Thank you all.

The solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
            {
                progressbars[i] = new ProgressBar();
                progressbars[i].Size = new Size(100, 10);
                progressbars[i].Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 70);
                progressbars[i].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                pbs[i] = new PictureBox();
                pbs[i].MouseEnter += globalPbsMouseEnterEvent;
                pbs[i].MouseLeave += globalPbsMouseLeaveEvent;
                pbs[i].Tag = "PB" + i.ToString();
                pbs[i].Size = new Size(100, 100);
                pbs[i].Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 60);
                pbs[i].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                pbs[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                Panel p = i < 4 ? panel1 : panel2;
                p.Controls.Add(pbs[i]);
                p.Controls.Add(progressbars[i]);
                pbs[i].BringToFront();
                progressbars[i].BringToFront();
            }
```